# Using Idiorm in PHP, how to serialise an ORM object after "find_one()" call

Tags: php, slim, idiorm

I am using "slim-json-api" in a project to access some data in a MySQL database. I am trying to pull back a single row and return this to the response, but I am getting no data back.

```
$app->get('/topics/:id', function($id) use ($app) {

    $topic = ORM::for_table('topics')->find_one($id);
    $posts = ORM::for_table('posts')->where('topics_id', $id)->find_array();

    $app->render(200, array(
        "topic" => $topic,
        "posts" => $posts
    ));
});
```

The result of this is as follows:

```
{
"topic": {},
"posts": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "user_id": "1",
        "topics_id": "1",
        "post_time": "2014-03-17 12:44:24",
        "post_subject": "I like this!",
        "post_text": "This is the body of an amazing post!"
    }
],
"error": false,
"status": 200
}
```

The annoying this about this is that I get a fully populated "posts" object and I know the data is present and correct in the DB. It is as if the array of results for "posts" is not an array of single returned value types.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should start checking if the generated query is exactly as expected: http://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#query-logging

Comment: You also should check that the `$id` you are passing matches the expected `id` field in the table as assumed by Idiorm.  Instead of just using `find_one($id)`, try doing a `->where('id', $id)->find_one()` and see if you get the right results.